# Is there is a difference between returning true and return to super class? in methods like setOnTouchListener()

Tags: android, performance

is there is a difference in performance or any other things if I just returned ***true*** instead of returning to the *superclass* like this `return PreviewActivity.super.onTouchEvent(event);`

Both of them works and I didn't notice any difference!!

```
previewLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return PreviewActivity.super.onTouchEvent(event); /*or return true*/
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference in performance if you choose to call and return the super method. The return value here is supposed to signify whether or not you have decided to consume the touch event. Returning true will mean you decided to consume/process this touch event and subsequent views (for instance, views underneath it in some cases) in the layout that could receive this touch event won't be given this touch event. In general, you shouldn't need to worry about the performance impact of the default super behavior of the `onTouchEvent` method unless you overrode and implemented your own touch handling that might do something complex.